# How to attach dynamic popover to certain element in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, validation, popover

#### Short description

We want to have **one** directive which shows different content (based upon form validation). This should be then attached to the corresponding field with the error (placed next to it).

#### Background

We have a usual form with a couple of fields. Once the users clicks on the submit-button there is a validation happening and if anything goes wrong this should happen:

1. Load a certain message a la 'This should be a valid email address.' depending on the field/input.
2. **Show a popover / tooltip or however you call it with that message next to that field.** - this is what I am asking.
3. Scroll to that element

**I want to know how to achieve in Number 2.** That could be solved by adding a corresponding popover declaration in each field however it should be a generic approach where the validation should know the fields to check and then handle the popover. Think of more than one form on different app-states, ideally the content should be managed in one place instead of many and there should be one call to the validation method as well as one call to the show-popover method.

In AngularJS there should be no manipulation of the DOM so the idea is to have a service or directive or something alike which loads the popover and attaches it to the corresponding element.

How would you go with this? My idea here is to have one hidden popover directive on page load. When the validation is happening this should be displayed and then play with $position.

This could get messy as there has to be many situations thought about (i.e. element on the very right and the popover placed on the right - the user can't see the popover) and I don't want to reinvent the wheel. A code example would be appreciated if you answer on this one.

Is this the way to go here or are there any better solutions? I'd prefer to use a standard library which handles the popover functionality - we already have mm-foundation working. Then how to attach this dynamically to the input field without writing popover-code on each field to validate?

Doing this in jQuery is easy but how about AngularJS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If doing it in jQuery is easy, in AngularJS is trivial ;)

Here's an example:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="size" name="size" min="0" max="10" integer />{{size}}<br />
<span ng-show="form.size.$error.integer">The value is not a valid integer!</span>
```

In AngularJS, for each form element, you can assign a set of validation rules, like min-value, max-value, not null, e-mail and so forth. The validation is automatically triggered when there's any interaction between the user and the mentioned element. For each validation rule, there's a type of error that's triggered. You just have to pick what kind of error you want to handle. Then you can use the tag "ng-show='condition'" to display the popover element. It will be shown when the condition is true, as you can see in ng-show="form.size.$error.integer". All of this is automatically done for you.
You can also create you own validations, but it takes some extra few lines of code. It's not so hard, though.

You can refer to this page in order to learn more about what I just said: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: That point into one direction but how about the one directive? With your solution I still have to add x span-tags everywhere. My question is more about having one directive which I fill and then attach it to the field in question.

Comment: That wasn't your original question. You just edited it. Anyway, writing a directive is still doable. From your directive, you can check what validations are being applied to the element and check the respective validation errors being thrown.

Comment: Jodevan, I added the first four lines since you didn't understand what I mean and to make it more clear to others as well. Still no success: The question is NOT about the errors but about creating a popover directive and position it next to the field where it should be attached to. Any suggestions to that?